# 2D pointer pointing 2D array in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays

1. How to make a 2d pointer like **check point a 2d array like
   mycheck[][]?
2. How to convert a 1d like check[16], to 2d array like mycheck[4][4]?

My attempt

```
float (*mycheck)[4] = (float (*)[4]) check;
```

But if second time I want to use mycheck again for some other 1d array, how can I do?
 My attempt:

```
float (*mycheck)[4] = (float (*)[4]) other1darray;
```

this will definitely give a re-declaration error.

Comment: I'm quite certain there is more code to this than that.

Comment: THe first question is strange, because a **check pointer is in essence an arrya if you allocate the memory

Comment: Do you want C or C++? Or can I randomly slap haskell and python on that too?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is that you cannot do that. All you can do is allocate some memory and copy the data over.

The answer to the second question is very simple

```
mycheck = (float (*)[4]) other1darray;
```

You only have to declare variables once, after that just use the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Array a[] decays to a pointer to the first element when you drop the []. This does not happen recursively, in other words, it doesn't work for a[][].

Secondly, you can't assign arrays in C. You can ONLY initialize them. You will have to set each member yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2D array in C like this.
Use a typedef to make it easier.

```
typedef int **matrix;

matrix create2Darray(int row, int col)
{
    int idx;
    matrix m = malloc(row * sizeof(int*));
    for (idx = 0; idx < row; ++idx)
    {
        m[idx] = malloc(col * sizeof(int));
    }
    return m;
}
```

And then call this in another function;

```
matrix check = create2Darray(2, 2);
```

Comment: i get this sorts of error when i compile the code |In function 'int**create2Darray(int, int)':|
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\check.cpp|9|error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'matrix {aka int**}' [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\check.cpp|12|error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
"

Comment: that is cuz of your compiler. some compilers want you to cast the result of malloc which is a void  to the desired type. I don't tend to do that cuz gcc matches it normally, preventing me from making errors. In your case if you cast the outcome of malloc to (int**) and (int*) your fine

Comment: Ya i was foolish last time i forget to cast that and i figure it out as soon as i argue for the error message, but this time i am little bit confuse that with your declearatoin i can excess an array of size m[4][n]; where n being any number accepted by memory.......such as i can assign m[3][115] = 7; and can print it out but as i think i was suppose to excess up to m[row][col] where row = 4 and col = 4.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a 1D array to a 2D array you can assign the pointers to the right position in the array. An example below. It also show how to create a 2D array dynamically, but I commented it out, since it is not needed for the example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float **matrix;
    float *array;

    array = (float *) malloc(16 * sizeof(float));
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx != 16; ++idx)
    {
        array[idx] = idx;
    }

    matrix = (float **) malloc(4 * sizeof(float *));
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx != 4; ++idx)
    {
        // matrix[idx] = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
        matrix[idx] = &array[idx * 4];
    }


    for (size_t row = 0; row != 4; ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col != 4; ++col)
        {
            printf("%.1f ", matrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Note: this makes the 1D array and 2D array point to the same memory. If you change something in the 1D it also changes in the 2D and vice-versa. If you don't want this, first copy the array.